# SQL Server Login Authentication vs Trusted WIndows Login Which one is Better

Tags: sql, security, web-applications

Is there an advantage in using a trusted connection vs a sql login for web application?  Is there any pros/cons from one to another?

Answer (score 3):

I usually use Windows Authentication, which is more secure, with a service account. If you are doing an internal application within your own domain and you want to authenticate your users to the database server, you will need to set up delegation on that service account along with the IIS and SQL services. If it is outward facing or you aren't concerned with authenticating users to the database, you simply need to give the relevant permissions to the service account login in SQL. In either case, assuming your webserver is IIS, you would change the web application to run under the service account. This will encrypt and store the credentials on the webserver.

The main reason windows authentication is more secure is it makes use of the Active Directory infrastructure to authenticate users using encrypted messages between the servers. With SQL Authentication the credentials are passed across the network. If you do use SQL Authentication, you should make sure to encrypt the connection string portion of your web config, as you would embed the credentials including the password.